# Posting to Facebook Newsfeed using Graph API in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a message to a user's feed (wall).

I've already got the `publish_stream` permission and have the user's id (`$fbid`) and access token (`$access_token`), however I am only able to post an empty message to the wall.

This is what the post looks like:

> User Name
>
> Like · Comment · 12 minutes ago via AppName

So basically all the content of the message is missing (everything in the `$data` variable).

This is the code I used:

```
include 'facebook.php'; 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(appId =>  $app_id,
                               secret => $app_secret,
                               cookie => true));

$data['post'] = array('access_token' => $access_token,
                      'message' => 'Sign up now',
                      'picture' => 'http://myurl.com/images/pic.jpg',
                      'link' => 'http://myurl.com/',
                      'caption' => 'Get early access to our app'); 

$post_id = $facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/feed/', 'post', $data);
```

What am I missing? Why is `$data` content not displayed in the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `$data['post']` you are not sending correct data to the API.

Change it to `$data` I am not really sure why you have the 'post' part in there for.

If you need it in the format `$data['post']` then change your API call to read

```
$post_id = $facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/feed/', 'post', $data['post']);
```

See example at https://gist.github.com/3378724

Comment: Hi,I tried both options and they don't even make an empty post :(

Comment: I switched $data with the actual array() in the $facebook->api and it now works. Thanks :-)

Comment: Yeah that works... but there is not need to do that... please refer to example I posted above your comment. Also please read up on how to use arrays in PHP, anyway glad it worked out for you.